# BINARY SEARCH TREE creation

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

i have written a simple code to create and insert elements into a binary search tree, when i write the code in the following manner, the chaining doesn't seem to happen, can anybody help me understand what exactly is happening in the insert function ? I know the code to insert elements into a binary search tree, just curious to know why this one doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node {
    struct node *left;
    struct node* right;
    int element;
};

void insert(struct node *node,int x) {
    if(node==NULL) {
        node=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        node->element=x;
        node->left=NULL;
        node->right=NULL;
    } else {
        if(x<node->element) {
            insert(node->left,x);}
        else {
            insert(node->right,x);
        }
    }
}

void inorder(struct node *base) {
    if(base!=NULL) {
        inorder(base->left);
        printf("%d ",base->element);
        inorder(base->right);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct node *base;
    base=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    base->element=1;
    base->left=NULL;
    base->right=NULL;
    insert(base,25);
    insert(base,30);
    inorder(base);

    return 0;
}
```

if the insert function is written this way, it works but still doesn't work for creation of the first node of the binary search tree, confused :/

```
void insert2(struct node *node,int x) {
    if(node==NULL) {
        node=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        node->element=x;
        node->left=NULL;
        node->right=NULL;
    } else {
        if(x<node->element) {
            if(node->left==NULL) {
                node->left=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                node->left->element=x;
                node->left->left=NULL;
                node->left->right=NULL;
            } else {
                insert2(node->left,x);
            }
        } else {
            if(node->right==NULL) {
                node->right=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                node->right->element=x;
                node->right->left=NULL;
                node->right->right=NULL;
            } else {
                insert2(node->right,x);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In `insert()`, you are just modifying the local `node` variable while creating a new node.

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc`](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html)...

Comment: I totally understand that you're having a hard time debugging your code. Start by putting the code into a readable form (indentation, placement of braces etc). Then either use a debugger or put more printf's to understand the flow of the program.

Comment: @stefan, i just have one problem in the question, the code is pretty understandable, the way the pointers behave is what confuses me in this one

Comment: @Kishore, isn't *node taking the adress of *base ??

Comment: in `node=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));`, you are assigning the address of the newly allocated space to the local variable `node`. So once the control goes out of your function, you won't have access to it. Now, that's a memory leak.

Comment: @Kishore, how to correct it or how to relate it to the pointer in the calling function ?

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour, i didnt't get you, if i don't cast it, hw will it be a pointer of type struct node* ?,btw thanks for editing, i deleted that answer

Comment: The conversion between `void *` and `struct node *` is implicit when you use a C compiler, so there is no need for an explicit conversion. If you're not using a C compiler, then you're not programming in C. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) for more information.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour , ok i'll remove it, but what about relating *node to *base, what should i do about that ? is there a way ? or  will I have to compulsorily use a double pointer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a value to a function in C, you're using pass-by-value. What that means is the value gets copied into another variable which becomes local to the function.

```
void change(struct node *n) {
    n = 42;
}

int main(void) {
    change(NULL); // change can't change the value of NULL, can it?
}
```

Now take a look at your `insert` function... Suppose I call `insert(NULL,42);`, do you think `insert` is trying to change `NULL`? Or is it trying to change some local variable, which your `main` function can't see?

You know what needs to be done already... Either make your `insert` function use an extra level of pointer indirection as you've suggested in your comments, or return the root node from `insert` so that you can propagate the changes made by `insert` into the data structure stored in `main` (using the assignment `=` operator).

Answer (score 1):

C is pass-by-value. When you pass something into a function's parameter, the function makes a copy of it. So when you pass a `struct node pointer` into the `insert` function, C makes a copy of that pointer.

What you did in `main` is first you made a `struct node* base`:

`base --> struct node`.

When you call `insert(base, 25)`, C makes a copy of base. So now in your memory you have something like this:

```
basecpy ---> [struct node] <--- base
```

So in your `insert`, you are essentially doing

```
if(basecpy==NULL)
    {basecpy=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    basecpy->element=x;
    basecpy->left=NULL;
    basecpy->right=NULL;}
```

Which does not change `base` in anyway at all - it just changes `basecpy`.

This can be solved by using double pointers:

```
void insert(struct node **node, int x) {
    if (*node == NULL) {
        *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
        (*node)->element=x;
        (*node)->left=NULL;
        (*node)->right=NULL;
    } else {
        if (x < (*node)->element) {
            insert(&((*node)->left), x);
        } else {
            insert(&((*node)->right), x);
        }
    }
}
```

And then to use it, pass in the *address* of base.

```
insert(&base, 25);
```

Pointers can be tricky :)

[ideone](http://ideone.com/JlOi8G)